# Generalizing primality to other operations

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

(By "number" below I always mean an element of $\mathbb{Z}^+\setminus $$\left\{1\right \}$.)

We all know that a number $p$ is prime iff it cannot be represented as $ab$ for any two numbers $a$ and $b$. That got me thinking: can we generalize primality to arbitrary operations? Hear me out. We can come up with the following definition:

> A number $p$ is $+$-prime iff it cannot be represented as $a+b$ for any two numbers $a$ and $b$.

But such a definition is pointless, and there is nothing to investigate here: it's obvious that the only $+$-primes are $2$ and $3$.

We can go further and come up with another definition:

> A number $p$ is e-prime ("e" for "exponentiation") iff it cannot be represented as $a^b$ for any two numbers $a$ and $b$.

This is a little more interesting. For example, the first five e-primes are $2$, $3$, $5$, $6$ and $7$.

We can go even further by using [hyperoperations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation):

> A number $p$ is $\uparrow ^n$-prime (for a number $n\geq2$) iff it cannot be represented as $a\uparrow ^nb$ for any two numbers $a$ and $b$.

Does such a generalization exist in mathematics already? If it does, where can I read about it (books, papers, etc.)? To me personally, for example, e-primality sounds like something I would definitely want to learn more about.

Comment: The e-primes look to be the complement of the set of nontrivial perfect powers. So in one sense something has been done, namely the theorem that the difference of two nontrivial perfect powers can only be 1 in the case $3^2-2^3.$ (This is only a fact about e-primes in a roundabout way.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer from me to my own question :)

As @coffeemath has noted above, the e-primes are the complement of the set of nontrivial perfect powers. In other words (and under my made-up terminology) the perfect powers are the e-composite numbers. So, learning about the e-primes is essentially learning about the perfect powers (e.g. [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL14/Jakimczuk3/jakimczuk21.pdf) is a nice paper on the distribution of perfect powers).

As for $\uparrow ^n$-primes, I don't know anything.

An obvious thing to note is that the "deeper" down this made-up hierarchy of mine we go, the more often the primes of a particular "type" appear. That is, there are only two $+$-primes, infinitely many regular primes, infinitely many e-primes (as far as I know) - but even though there are infinitely many of these, they still seem to crop up a lot more often than regular primes. I imagine that the pattern continues with $\uparrow^n$-primes because the numbers involved grow insanely fast, hence the giant gaps between any two consecutive $\uparrow ^n$-composites.

That's a very short summary of what I've found. Feel free to add your findings :)